# Make table rows collapsible with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tree, treeview

I have a table with some rows. Each row get a `data-id` attribute and all 'child' nodes get a `data-parent-id` attribute.

```
<table>
    <tr data-id="1"></tr>
      <tr data-id="1-1" data-parent-id="1"></tr>
        <tr data-id="1-1-1" data-parent-id="1-1"></tr>
          <tr data-id="1-1-1-1" data-parent-id="1-1-1"></tr>
    <tr data-id="2></tr>
      <tr data-id="2-1" data-parent-id="2"></tr>
      <tr data-id="2-2" data-parent-id="2"></tr>
        <tr data-id="2-2-1" data-parent-id="2-2"></tr>
        <tr data-id="2-2-2" data-parent-id="2-2"></tr>
        <tr data-id="2-2-3" data-parent-id="2-2"></tr>
    <tr data-id="3"></tr>
</table>
```

I have made indentions in the code, so it's easier to see child/parent relationship.

How can I make these table rows collapsible?

I have made this javascript

```
$('tr[data-id]').css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function() {
    var parentId = $(this).attr('data-id');

    // set status
    $(this).toggleClass('expanded collapsed');

    // collapse/expand child nodes
    $("tr[data-parent-id='" + parentId + "']").toggleClass('hidden');

    // icon
    $(this).children('td').children('i').toggleClass('fa-caret-right fa-caret-down');
});
```

It does collapse and expand the table rows, but if all the rows are expanded and I try to collapse of the 'highest leveled' nodes it only collapses the first child, but not the deeper levels.

How can I make sure it collapses an entire level?

I thought of using `nextAll('tr[data-parent-id]').each(function ....` something.

Comment: highest level node does it mean ur first TR?

Comment: Just a side notice - quite a strange mix of assigning style and binding an event handler - `$('tr[data-id]').css(...).click(...)`. I think it's better to use separate CSS class with required styles.

Comment: Ilya: The reason why I set the css in the javascript is because the cursor shouldn't change if the javascript is not applied to the table.

Comment: oh, why don't u wrap ur child inside parent TR, since ur child is a TR element, then u should wrap it with another table, it will be easier to achieve what u want with that structure.